# How can I modify the default date format for "moments" in photos?

Tags: photos

I'm running photos 1.5. Older versions of Photos used a different date format for the title of moments. Right now most of my pictures are organized using the old date format (YYYY-MM-DD). Is there a way to modify the date format for all moments in the latest version of Photos?

[image]

Comment: Check your format in System preferences -> Language & Region -> Advanced... -> Dates - modify there as you wish; these are your locale settings. Note the format (YYYY-MM-DD) is not old, it is just the ISO standard today.

Comment: Great suggestion. I've updated this setting in preferences and restarted the photos app but the dates are still showing up the same way (MM-DD-YYYY). I wonder if I'll have to re-import all these pictures to have it read the EXIF data again. Let me try that.

Comment: Actually it looks like exporting them picked up the new Date format. Awesome! Thank you! Put this down as the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your format in System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Advanced... -> Dates and modify there by drag and drop the dates fields as you wish. These correspond to your locale settings. Note the format (YYYY-MM-DD) is not old, it is just the ISO standard today.

Comment: This fixes it for pictures you export after modifying the date format. The date format within the app still shows the previous way. Not sure if there's a way to change that but It's not important for my use case.